# Filtering Search Results by Category

Tags: entries, categories, search, filter

I'm currently trying to filter my search results by category, I've been following [this tutorial](https://craftcookbook.net/recipes/universal-category-filters) but cannot get it to work. It keeps not adding on the category parameter, but instead just replaces the search parameter like so:

**On search:**
"/search/?q=dress"

**On Clicking a Filter:**
"/search/?category=wedges"

Below is the code running my search box:

```
<div class="search-box w-form">
  <form action="search/" class="form">
    <input type="text" class="text-field w-input" maxlength="256" type="search" autofocus="true" name="q" data-name="Name" placeholder="e.g. Black Dress" id="name">
    <input type="submit" data-wait="Please wait..." class="search-field-go w-button" value="">
  </form>
</div>
```

and the code running the results page:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% if craft.request.getParam('category') is not null %}
    {% set category = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getParam('category')) %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score').relatedTo(category).find() %}
{% else %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}
{% endif %}

{% include 'search/_filters' %}

<!-- SEARCH CONTAINER -->

{% if entries|length %}
    <p>{{ entries|length }} results:</p>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Your search for “{{ query }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
{% endif %}

<ul>
   {% for category in craft.categories.group('womens').find() %}
    <li>
            <a href="{{craft.request.url}}/?category={{ category.slug }}">{{ category.title}} </a>
         </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line here (reformatted for legibilty):

```
<a href="{{craft.request.url}}/?category={{ category.slug }}">
  {{ category.title}}
</a>
```

You are generating the url by from [craft.request.url](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getUrl) and appending the category. But the original query is not part of the url at this point. I think this will work and be clearer:

```
<a href="{{ url(craft.request.path, {q: query, category: category.slug}) }}">
  {{ category.title}}
</a>
```

This uses the [url](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions#url) function, passing it the query string parameters.